# Adding a TextWatcher via addTextChangedListener on EditText has no effect

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am attempting to attach a TextWatcher to an EditText. This is done in onCreate(). I know that the EditText is being found successfully. However, when the activity launches, nothing happens when making changes in EditText. I have tried editing the code within the three overridden functions in the TextWatcher to do something besides call a function, but that also has no effect

Relevant code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
    EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cost);
    myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            updatePrice(null);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){
            updatePrice(null);
        }
    });
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

And from the layout:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/cost"
     ... 
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
```

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity         ComponentInfo{com.example.paymeback/com.example.paymeback.MainActivity}:     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f07003c     (com.example.paymeback:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{b1d7ce60 #0     id=0x7f07003c}
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f07003c (com.example.paymeback:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{b1d7ce60 #0 id=0x7f07003c}
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:919)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
```

Comment: why are you calling `setContentView` twice?

Comment: No idea! It crashes if I don't set back to main_activity. And I couldn't access R.id.code without setting the content view to fragment_main

Comment: It says that com.example.paymeback:id/container doesn't exist and you're calling it when the savedInstance is null

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `setContentView` three times. Why? You should call it only once. The `EditText` you're adding the `TextWatcher` to is getting disposed when you replace the content view on your activity on your last call to `setContentView`, so whatever `EditText` you're typing into when your activity launches, is not the same you added the watcher to.

Comment: That makes sense, any idea why, if I don't set the content view to main_activity before I exit onCreate, the whole thing crashes?

Comment: What exception are you getting when it crashes?

Comment: I added in the stack trace

Comment: Also remove your second `setContentView` call: `setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);` And put all of your views in your `activity_main` xml file.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how the different activities work with each other (main activity launches main fragment?) but I do know that I can't touch R.id.cost when the contentview is set to main_activity, since R.id.cost exists within main fragment. There must be something I'm missing